# When and Why the occurrence of the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

My Source Code is as follows and it is in Python Scripting Language:

```
d = [frozenset({[[1]*2, (2, 3)*3]*4}), {5, }, {6: '', 9: " "}]
print(d, sep = '\t')
for k in d:
    print(k, type(k), sep = '\t')
```

My output message is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" E:/Observations/LISTS/basics.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Observations/LISTS/basics.py", line 144, in <module>
    d = [frozenset({[[1]*2, (2, 3)*3]*4}), {5, }, {6: '', 9: " "}]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're attempting to put a mutable list object in a set, which you can't do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: But, as per the python built-in data structures features, every data structure may contain any other data structure, My intention is to observe which data structure contain all the other data structures including that, and to notice in which order they will appear as a compound data structure.

Comment: That is not true. I'm not sure where you heard that. Mutable objects, in general, cannot be keys to sets or dictionaries, or in any other context that would require the structure to be hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the list inside the dictionary which is a list which cannot be hashed. Which can be solved by converting the internal nested lists to a tuple like this,

```
d = [frozenset({((1)*2, (2, 3)*3)*4}), {5, }, {6: '', 9: " "}]
```

Comment: I got the output that i was expected, but the only change is that instead of list it was replaced by tuple. As you described in your answer, list is a member of the dictionary object, kindly please! observe my code, once again. Dictionary is a member in the list., you stated vice-versa which is not true according to the code posted by me in the question., So, kindly provide me some clarification on it. Thank You Sir.....

Comment: Thank You Sir, Now i was got clarified....

Comment: In you code, you have most outer list  which is [frozenset(...), ..., ...] . Here in the section of frozenset you have a dictionary which contain the list. i.e. {[[1]*2, (2, 3)*3]*4} . So your dictionary has list in it and when you try to create the frozenset of that dictionary (which contain list) it throws error that list cannot be hashed. 
The reason behind is that only immutable things can be hashed. The list is mutable so it cannot be hashed and it throws the error.
If you find my answer useful, kindly vote up to my answer. Thanks

Comment: I got clarified before this response, sir. Thank you sir, just now i voted up to your answer.